# 90's vampire anthology book, including a story about vampires having taken over, told by a vampire's servant, killed by a nun

Tags: story-identification, horror, vampire, anthology-book

I remember really loving this book when I read it in 7th grade.

Though the only story in the book I explicitly remember is one about a future in which vampires have taken over the country and use human servants, who wear crescent moon earrings, to find their victims.

The story is told from the perspective of a vampire's servant who references the Metallica song "Enter Sandman".
The protagonist is lured into a trap and is killed at the end by a nun who turns out to be a murdering vigilante who kills vampires and their servants.

The book had to be released sometime inbetween 1991 (since it references the Metallica song) and 1999.

I also remember at least one of the stories being sexually explicit with a graphic depiction of sex; whether it found its way into the school library by mistake or it was just tame enough to still be YA, I'm not sure.

Comment: You say "...the only story in the book..." Does that mean it was a collection of short stories/an anthology or that that is the main plot line you remember?

Comment: It was an anthology of short stories. I meant that was the only short story whose plot I could explicitly remember.

Comment: They were all vampire stories?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Comment: Do the details from this [unanswered reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/1uxsl9/tomt_90s_short_fiction_us_conquered_by_vampires/) ring any bells by chance?

Comment: I DO remember the line "I'll stop when they stop" closed out the story, yet I also remember the nun saying this after she kills the servant, who she tied to a chair, with a razor blade or knife and walks away. She didn't fight a vampire in the story I read, nor did she rig the servant's body to explode. The story referenced in the reddit seems like it could have been a sequel to the one I read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### [*Dracula: Prince of Darkness*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Dracula-Darkness-science-fiction-1992-09-24/dp/B01HC0ZFJG/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1474057056&sr=1-3&keywords=dracula%3A%20prince%20of%20darkness%20book)

[image: book cover, picturing a black-and-white Dracula]

This anthology of vampire tales was published in 1992, so it fits the time frame. The story you remember is probably “The Lord’s Work,” which features a vampire-killing nun. It seems to match the details you remember:

- The nun does say “I’ll stop when they stop.” She also has an internal voice like the one mentioned in the linked Reddit post.

  > And I suppose you’ll be starting up this same awful sinfulness again,
  >   won’t you?
  >   When is it going to END, Carole? When are you going to STOP?
  >
  > “I’ll stop when they stop,” Sister Carole said aloud to the night
- The vampires’ servant references “Enter Sandman.”

  > He closed his eyes as the body tumbled downward.
  >   He hummed Metallica’s song “Enter Sandman” to blot out the sound it made when it hit the pavement.
- And of course, the crescent earrings:

  > Twenty years, and out. Like the army. They gave you those
  >   crescent-moon earrings to wear, so they’d know you were on their side when they ran into you at night, and they’d let you do pretty much what you wanted.

Comment: By F. Paul Wilson, no wonder that story was memorable. Apparently he later included this story as a chapter in his "Midnight Mass" novel as well. I greatly appreciate the help. Now off to Amazon!

Comment: {throws hands up in the air} I ran into "Midnight Mass" in my search, but discounted it because I didn't think the other details matched. Go figure. :-P

Answer (score -1):

[*Under the Fang*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/748523.Under_the_Fang#) (1991). This was an anthology about vampires that took over the world released about that time; think zombie apocalypse but in lieu of zombies it was vampires.

[image: book cover, title and author's name stylized as coffin]